# Ajax call to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I have created few textboxes and Images with unique IDs in my .aspx file. I need to update these items every 5 seconds through an ajax call to my Microsoft SQL Server database. Details of values to be displayed in all textboxes and dynamic images are stored in separate views.

Currently I am refreshing the page every 5 seconds but it is not economical as the fetch phenomena of every images either static or dynamic is causing too much bandwidth load to the network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use setTimeout function or interval

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using an old, unsupported version of SQL Server, you cannot directly make AJAX calls to the database. You need to setup an application (a.k.a. middle tier) server to translate the AJAX calls into SQL calls.

This application server can be written in C#, Java, Ruby, PHP, Python, etc. so a comprehensive answer is not possible here.

Comment: Can you please share the sample C# file for the same

Comment: Start here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Or maybe copy the patterns used in this one: https://github.com/docevaad/AWHumanResources